# Open addressing linear probing hash map

Tags: c, hash-map

Here is my wheel. `strmap` - C string hash map.

Main goal - create usable and simple alternative to `hcreate_r`, `hdestroy_r`, `hsearch_r` GNU extensions.

I am looking for general review of my code.
But any other suggestion and criticism (functionality, usability, code style, performance, memory usage, ...) are welcome.

Compile test&benchmark - `g++ -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o ht ht.cc strmap.c`

**strmap.h**

```
/**
  @file strmap.h
  @brief STRMAP - simple alternative to hcreate_r, hdestroy_r, hsearch_r GNU extensions
  @date 2021
  @license Public Domain
*/

#ifndef _STRMAP_H
#define _STRMAP_H

typedef struct STRMAP strmap;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/**
  @brief Create a string map which can contain at least `size` elements
*/
strmap *sm_create(uint32_t size);

/**
  @brief Retrieves user associated data for given key
*/
bool sm_lookup(strmap *sm, const char *key, void **data);

/**
  @brief Insert key (if not exists) and user data
*/
bool sm_insert(strmap *sm, const char *key, const void *data);

/**
  @brief Update user data for given key
*/
bool sm_update(strmap *sm, const char *key, const void *data);

/**
  @brief Update user data for given key or insert if key not exists
*/
bool sm_upsert(strmap *sm, const char *key, const void *data);

/**
  @brief Remove key

  Based on 
  M. A. Kolosovskiy, "Simple implementation of deletion from open-address hash table"
  https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0909/0909.2547.pdf
*/
bool sm_remove(strmap *sm, const char *key);

/**
  @brief Remove all keys
*/
void sm_clear(strmap *sm);

/**
  @brief Return number of keys
*/
uint32_t sm_size(strmap *sm);

/**
  @brief Remove all keys and free memory allocated for the map structure
*/
void sm_free(strmap *sm);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**strmap.c**

```
/**
  @file strmap.c
  @brief STRMAP - simple alternative to hcreate_r, hdestroy_r, hsearch_r GNU extensions
  @date 2021
  @license Public Domain
*/

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "strmap.h"

#define MIN_SIZE 9

/**
  Daniel Lemire, A fast alternative to the modulo reduction
  https://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/
*/
#define FAST_REDUCE32(x, r) (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)(x) * (uint64_t)(r)) >> 32)

#ifdef USE_FAST_REDUCE
    #define POSITION(x, r) FAST_REDUCE32((x), (r))
#else
    #define POSITION(x, r) ((x) % (r))
#endif

#define DISTANCE(from, to, r) ((to) >= (from) ? (to) - (from) : (r) - ((from) - (to)))

struct SLOT {
    const char *key; // C null terminated string
    const void *data; // user data
    uint32_t hash; // key hash value
};

struct STRMAP {
    uint32_t capacity; // number of allocated slots
    uint32_t size; // number of keys in map   
    struct SLOT *ht;
};

static uint32_t FNV_1a(const char *key);

static void compress(strmap *sm, struct SLOT *slot);
static struct SLOT * find(strmap *sm, const char *key, uint32_t hash);

strmap * sm_create(uint32_t size)
{
    struct SLOT *ht;
    struct STRMAP *sm;
    uint32_t capacity;

    capacity = 4 * ((size >= MIN_SIZE ? size : MIN_SIZE) / 3);
    
    if (!(ht = (struct SLOT *)calloc(capacity, sizeof (struct SLOT)))) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if ((sm = (struct STRMAP *)calloc(1, sizeof (struct STRMAP)))) {
        sm->size = 0;
        sm->capacity = capacity;
        sm->ht = ht;
    }
    else {
        free(ht);
    }

    return sm;
}

bool sm_insert(strmap *sm, const char *key, const void *data)
{
    struct SLOT *slot;
    uint32_t hash;
    
    assert(sm);
    assert(key);

    if (sm->size == sm->capacity - 1) {
        return false;
    }

    hash = FNV_1a(key);
    slot = find(sm, key, hash);
    if (!(slot->key)) {
        slot->key = key;
        slot->data = data;
        slot->hash = hash;
        ++(sm->size);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool sm_update(strmap *sm, const char *key, const void *data) {
    struct SLOT *slot;
    uint32_t hash;

    assert(sm);
    assert(key);

    hash = FNV_1a(key);
    slot = find(sm, key, hash);
    if (slot->key) {
        slot->data = data;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool sm_upsert(strmap *sm, const char *key, const void *data) {
    struct SLOT *slot;
    uint32_t hash;

    assert(sm);
    assert(key);

    hash = FNV_1a(key);
    slot = find(sm, key, hash);
    if (slot->key) {
        slot->data = data;
        return true;
    }
    if (sm->size == sm->capacity - 1) {
        return false;
    }
    slot->key = key;
    slot->data = data;
    slot->hash = hash;
    ++(sm->size);
    return true;
}

bool sm_lookup(strmap *sm, const char *key, void **data)
{
    struct SLOT *slot;
    uint32_t hash;

    assert(sm);
    assert(key);

    hash = FNV_1a(key);
    slot = find(sm, key, hash);

    if (slot->key) {
        *data = (void *)slot->data;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool sm_remove(strmap *sm, const char *key)
{
    struct SLOT *slot;
    uint32_t hash;

    assert(sm);
    assert(key);

    hash = FNV_1a(key);
    slot = find(sm, key, hash);

    if (slot->key) {
        slot->key = 0;
        --(sm->size);
        compress(sm, slot);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void sm_clear(strmap *sm)
{
    assert(sm);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sm->capacity; ++i) {
        (sm->ht)[i].key = 0;
    }
    sm->size = 0;

}

uint32_t sm_size(strmap *sm)
{
    assert(sm);
    
    return sm->size;
}

void sm_free(strmap *sm)
{
    assert(sm);    

    free(sm->ht);
    free(sm);
}

/*
  private static functions
*/

/*
  find slot with given key and hash in collision chain or return first empty
*/
struct SLOT * find(strmap *sm, const char *key, uint32_t hash)
{
    struct SLOT *slot, *htEnd;

    slot = sm->ht + POSITION(hash, sm->capacity);
    htEnd = sm->ht + sm->capacity;

    while (slot->key) {
        if (hash == slot->hash) {
            if (!strcmp(key, slot->key)) {
                return slot;
            }
        }

        if (++slot == htEnd) {
            slot = sm->ht;
        }
    }

    return slot;
}

void compress(strmap *sm, struct SLOT *slot)
{
    struct SLOT *empty = slot, *htEnd;
    struct SLOT *root;

    htEnd = sm->ht + sm->capacity;
    if (++slot == htEnd) {
        slot = sm->ht;
    }

    while (slot->key) {
        root = sm->ht + POSITION(slot->hash, sm->capacity);
        if (DISTANCE(root, slot, sm->capacity) >= DISTANCE(empty, slot,
                sm->capacity)) {
            // swap current slot with empty
            empty->key = slot->key;
            empty->data = slot->data;
            empty->hash = slot->hash;
            slot->key = 0;
            empty = slot;
        }
        if (++slot == htEnd) {
            slot = sm->ht;
        }
    }
}

#define FNV_PRIME 16777619UL
#define FNV_OFFSET 2166136261UL
uint32_t FNV_1a(const char *key)
{
    uint32_t h = FNV_OFFSET;

    while (*key) {
        h ^= (unsigned char)*key;
        h *= FNV_PRIME;
        ++key;
    }

    return h;
}
#undef FNV_PRIME
#undef FNV_OFFSET
```

**ht.cc**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#define USE_FAST_REDUCE 1
#include "strmap.h"

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string xstr = "Zbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed;    
    
    // keys to insert 
    vector<string> keys;
    // not existing keys 
    vector<string> xkeys;
    
    // key value
    int val = 1551;
    // key value for update and upsert
    int uval = 7117;
    // pointer for lookup
    int *data;

    strmap *ht = sm_create(3700000);

    auto t1 = Clock::now();      
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
        random_shuffle(str.begin(), str.end());
        keys.push_back(str);
    }
    auto t2 = Clock::now();    
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Generate keys: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';
    
    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
        random_shuffle(xstr.begin(), xstr.end());
        xkeys.push_back(xstr);
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();    
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Generate not existing keys: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    cout << "*** strmap test ***\n";

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
        if (!sm_insert(ht, keys[i].c_str(), &val)) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i].c_str() << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Insert: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
        if (!sm_lookup(ht, keys[i].c_str(), (void **)&data)) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i] << '\n';
            break;
        }
        if (*data != 1551) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i] << " Data:" << *data << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Lookup existing: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
        if (!sm_update(ht, keys[i].c_str(), &uval)) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i].c_str() << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Update existing: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';
    
    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
        if (!sm_lookup(ht, keys[i].c_str(), (void **)&data)) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i] << '\n';
            break;
        }
        if (*data != 7117) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i] << " Data:" << *data << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Lookup updated: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
        if (sm_lookup(ht, xkeys[i].c_str(), (void **)&data)) {
            cout << "Error: " << xkeys[i] << '\n';  ;
            break;
        }
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Lookup not existing: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3000000; i++) {
        if (!sm_remove(ht, keys[i].c_str()))
            cout << keys[i];
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Remove: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3000000; i++) {
        if (!sm_upsert(ht, keys[i].c_str(), (void *)&uval)) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i].c_str() << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Upsert removed: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
        if (!sm_lookup(ht, keys[i].c_str(), (void **)&data)) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i] << '\n';
            break;
        }
        if (*data != 7117) {
            cout << "Error: " << keys[i] << " Data:" << *data << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Lookup: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    sm_free(ht);
    
    cout << "*** STL unordered_set test ***\n";
    unordered_set<string> strset;
    strset.reserve(3700000);
    
    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
      strset.insert(keys[i]);  
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Insert STL unordered_set: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
      strset.find(keys[i]);  
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Lookup existing STL unordered_set: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';

    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3700000; i++) {
      strset.find(xkeys[i]);  
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Lookup not existing STL unordered_set: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';
    
    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<3000000; i++) {
      strset.erase(keys[i]);  
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    elapsed = t2 - t1;
    cout << "Remove: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `size_t` for sizes

Use [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) consistently for sizes and array and loop indices. I recommend doing that even if you only store hashes internally as `uint32_t`.

## Missing `const`

You are using `const` already in some places, but you should also pass `sm` as a `const strmap *` in those functions that do not modify the map, such as `sm_lookup()`, `sm_size()` and `find()`.

## Typedefs can have exactly the same name as structs

Instead of using upper case for the name of a struct and lower case for the corresponding typedef, you can just give both the same (preferrably lower case) name:

```
typedef struct strmap strmap;
```

You can also typedef anonymous structs, which you could use for `struct SLOT`:

```
typedef struct {
    const char *key;
    const char *data;
    uint32_t hash;
} slot;
```

## Avoid macros

Macros are often not necessary, and can be replaced by static constants and functions. For example:

```
static const size_t min_size = 9;

static uint32_t fast_reduce32(uint32_t x, uint32_t r) {
    return ((uint64_t)x * r) >> 32;
}
```

Macros have all sorts of pitfalls. You are already putting everything inside parentheses, which is good, but even then there are issues. Consider writing:

```
if (DISTANCE(root, slot++, sm->capacity) ...) {...}
```

The macro expansion will evaluate `slot++` multiple times, which leads to unexpected results. Better to just make it a function:

```
size_t distance(slot *from, slot *to, size_t capacity) {
    return to >= from ? to - from : r - (from - to);
}
```

## Consider always using a power-of-two size

If you round up the requested size to the next power of two, you can avoid using the modulo operation.

## Missing assert

You are using `assert()` in the public API function to validate the arguments. That's great! You missed an `assert(data)` in `sm_lookup()` though.

## Consider adding a way to iterate over the hash map

Something missing from both the POSIX and GNU hash map functions is a way to iterate over all elements stored in the map. This makes it hard to put dynamically allocated data into a hash map, as at the end you have no way to free all the items stored in it. Adding a function which iterates over the map and calls a callback function for each item would help:

```
void sm_foreach(const strmap *sm, void (*action)(const char *key, void *data));
```

Comment: What about return values - bool vs enum vs int ?

Comment: `bool` for yes/no or success/failure, `enum` if there are multiple possibilities, `int` if you return a count of something (but prefer `size_t`). Apart from changing `uint32_t` to `size_t` for `sm_size()`, I think the return types you chose are perfectly fine.